# Interpolation of a 3D vector field in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vector, 3d, interpolation

I'm trying to interpolate a 3D vector field. For every `(x,y,z)` position we have a vector `(u,v,w)`. I have another set of points let's call them `(xq,yq,zq)` in which I don't have vector information `(uq,vq,wq)`. I would like to interpolate my data to find the vectors at the points `(xq,yq,zq)`.

I've tried to interpolate using several functions like griddata, by interpolating each vector component individually.

```
uq = griddata(x,y,z,u,xq,yq,zq);
vq = griddata(x,y,z,v,xq,yq,zq);
wq = griddata(x,y,z,w,xq,yq,zq);
```

I expect to obtain the vectors at the locations I specified, but the message I get is:

> "Warning: The underlying triangulation is empty - the points may be
>   coplanar or collinear."

Is there a better way to interpolate a vector field?

Comment: Please include a minimal example that we can run as is. Also, it is important that you specify if the `x,y,z` positions form a grid or are irregular

Comment: The warning indicate that your points are coplanar or collinear. Simply determine the equation of the plane (using 3 points) if your points are coplanar. Or determine the equation of the line (using 2 points) if your points are collinear.